# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') with game_id: result.data[0].game_id,` warning in my terminal,

What is weird is that the `console.log("result ", result);` shows me what I need, but below I can't access `result.data[0].game_id`

Code

```
return promise1.then((result) => {
      console.log("result ", result); <-- ALL GOOD HERE
      if (!result && !result.data && !result.data[0]) return;
      Stream.findOne({}).then((stream) => {
        if (!stream) {
          let streamInfos = new Stream({
            game_id: result.data[0].game_id, <-- ISSUE HERE
```

Output of the `console.log("result ", result);`

```
{"data":
[{
 "id":"45300981596",
 "user_id":"90849777",
 "user_login":"versifixion",
 "user_name":"VersifiXion",
 "game_id":"21779",
 "game_name":"League of Legends",
 "type":"live",
 "title":"VERSI | Stream test calculez pas | !reseaux",
 "viewer_count":1,
 "started_at":"2022-04-26T21:15:38Z",
 "language":"fr",
 "thumbnail_url":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_versifixion-{width}x{height}.jpg",
 "tag_ids":["6f655045-9989-4ef7-8f85-1edcec42d648"],
 "is_mature":false
}],
 "pagination":{}}
```

Comment: ok I needed to do a ```JSON.parse(result)```